# Is it possible to automatically redirect a Redmine wiki page to another page?

Tags: redirect, redmine, wiki

Is it possible to automatically redirect a Redmine wiki page to another page?

I mean a mechanism similar to Wikipedia's "redirected from..." so I can assign different titles to the same page (with one of them being the main one).

Answer (score 3):

I've just tried it with Redmine 3.1.0. You need access to the database. It's not that complicated, though it is not official.

Insert one line per redirect into the table `wiki_redirects`. You need the wiki id, which is the project id in normal cases. To find the id look into the `wikis` table.

Insert:

- `id`: (should be set by the database system)
- `wiki_id`: From which wiki should be redirected (is likely the same as `wiki_id` if redirecting takes place in a single wiki, and not across projects)
- `title`: The not existing page name from which will be redirected
- `created_on`: some date (I wouldn't use one which is in the future...)
- `redirects_to`: the target page name
- `redirects_to_wiki_id`: the target wiki id

Since your working in the database you have to maintain the entries there. Modifications and deletions have to be done there as well.

Comment: Thanks! I will try and let you know the results.